# AWS Route 53 mix GeoLocation and Latency policy behaviors

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation

In AWS Route 53 service,can I mix Latency policy with GeoLocation policy? e.g. I configure a CNAME with latency policy (in ap-southeast-1 Singapore) and the same CNAME with GeoLocation Singapore. How does Route 53 behave in this case? If a user from Singapore, will route53 give the GeoLocation or Latancy policy CNAME value?

Answer (score 3):

I tried doing this, it looks like though that Amazon AWS Route 53 requires that both records be the same type.

I was able to create two geolocation records that were both CNAME, or both A records. But I could not mix them. Meaning I could not have one A record and one CNAME record.

All that said you should be able to accomplish your goal this this. Create A records for the latency records. Then create CNAME's for your geolocation records and point one of your CNAME's to to the latency.

I tested this and it worked, I used the configuration below:

[image]